# Telugu RTS layout (m17n) missing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout, language-support

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on our new hard disk. Installed language-pack-te. Ibus now gave two layout choices for Telugu, but **Telugu-RTS layout** which has been there in all previous versions of Ubuntu is missing. 
What happened? Why is it missing from ibus-m17n now?
If it is no longer included in the new default m17n, how do I get that keyboard layout into my installation?  Anyone please help.

Comment: Have you tried to relogin after you installed `ibus-m17n`? Is IBus selected in _Language Support_?

Comment: Restarted IBus a couple of times and the problem got resolved sir, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Restarted Ibus (ibus restart) a couple of times and bingo, more layouts appeared, including telugu-rts.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 you are supposed to select _System Settings -> Text Entry_ to select input sources. You shouldn't need to do it in _IBus Preferences_.

Comment: Tried system settings - -> text entry first.  Telugu RTS was missing in that list.  ibus restart from terminal seems to have resolved the issue.  (I had in fact shut down and restarted my system after adding telugu to the language support, that did not help somehow).

Comment: Adding the Telugo language does not install `ibus-m17n` (maybe it should...). So the order should be: 1. Install `ibus-m17n`, 2. Log out and log in again, and 3. Find the m17n options in _Text Entry_.